# Feed crops text badly on tablet

Tags: bug, android-app

The main screen of the app looks pretty sorry on my Galaxy Tab 8.4 tablet (screen: 2560x1600):
[image]

The case is the same in portrait mode.

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: SM-T700

  - OS Version: 5.0.2 (T700XXU1BOL1)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Right, looks like the same error. Sorry, I did not find that one. It is pretty annoying though, makes feed very uncomfortable...

Comment: Note: AFAIK the Android client's development is halted since 2016, this is why the bug also hasn't been fixed.